# Angular built-in pipe - refer input value from previous pipe

Tags: angular

I have a custom pipe which returns an object and I need to refer a property of that object in the currency built-in pipe.

consider this example:

**price-pipe.js:**

```
@Pipe({name: 'price'})
export class PricePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(device: any): string {
         // ...some logic
         return {
             value: device.price,
             currencyCode: device.currencyCode
         }

    }
}
```

**device.html**

```
<div>
/* I need to take "currencyCode from the price pipe and pass it as parameter to currency pipe */
{{device | price | currency}} 
</div>
```

Is there a way to refer to a previous pipe returned value **without** customizing the built-in currency pipe?

Answer (score 1):

This is an elegant way to solve this scenario:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(device | price) as priceData">
    {{priceData.value | currency: priceData.currencyCode}}
</ng-container>
```

live example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mq7k42xm8y)

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in Pipes in your TypeScript :

```
import {CurrencyPipe} from '@angular/common'
constructor(private cp: CurrencyPipe) { ... }

this.value = 12345;
this.value = this.cp.transform(this.value, 'USD': true: '1.0-0'); // $12,345
```